# como sumar la diagonal de derecha a izquierda en una matriz

Tags: c#

---

Buenas noches, logré sumar la diagonal de izquierda derecha es decir desde la posición 0,0 , pero no he logrado sumar la diagonal de derecha a izquierda en un ejemplo de una matriz de 3 x 3. el código que voy a mostrar es solo de la suma de la diagonal, por favor me pueden asesorar como sumar la otra diagonal. Gracia.

```
Console.WriteLine("sumadiagonal de izuierda  a derecha");
  for (j = 0; j < matriz.GetLength(0); j++)
    {
      for (i = 0; i < matriz.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
          if (i == j)
            {
              sumadiagonal1 += matriz[i, j];
            }
        }
    }
Console.WriteLine("La suma de la diagonal 1 es =" + sumadiagonal1);
```

Comment: Cual es la razon detras de la condicional `if (i == j)`?

Comment: permite encontrar la posicion i con la posicion j , recorriendo asi solo la diagonal , llevandola a la variable sumadiagonal1  y luego se imprime la suma

Answer (score 1):

**Asesorándote**

Siendo tu matriz de 3x3, la lógica a considerar sería, por ejemplo:

> ```
> +---+---+---+   Valor   [i , j]       i + j
> | 1 | 2 | 1 |     1   = [0 , 2]  =>     2
> +---+---+---+
> | 3 | 4 | 1 |     4   = [1 , 1]  =>     2
> +---+---+---+
> | 5 | 6 | 3 |     5   = [2 , 0]  =>     2
> +---+---+---+
>
> 1 + 4 + 5 = 10
> ```

Donde, `i` y `j` son indices de tus filas y columnas respectivamente.

Además, podrás apreciar que la suma de ambos `i + j = 3 - 1`.

---

Por ejemplo:

```
int[,] matriz = new int[3, 3] { { 1, 2, 1 }, { 3, 4, 1 }, { 5, 6, 3 } };    

int cantFilas = matriz.GetLength(0);
int cantColumnas = matriz.GetLength(1);

if(cantFilas != cantColumnas){
    Console.WriteLine("No es una matriz cuadrada");
    return;
}

for (int i = 0; i < cantFilas; i++)
{            
    int j = ((cantFilas - 1) - i);

    Console.WriteLine("{0} = [{1} , {2}]", matriz[i, j], i , j);                
}
```

Obtendrás:

> ```
> 1 = [0 , 2]
> 4 = [1 , 1]
> 5 = [2 , 0]
> ```

[**DEMO**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5ZnZo3)

Comment: me ayudaría por favor , cual es la condicion dentro del for() para lograr llevar a una variable que sume la diagonal , solo requiero entender la condicion

Comment: @jorge esperaba que con el asesoriamiento ya podrías obtener los índices.  Acabo de complementar mi respuesta agregando el código de como obtener los índices para los valores `i` y `j`.

Answer (score 1):

Para calcular la diagonal de izquierda a derecha, no es necesario un `for anidado`, dado que es una matriz cuadrada con un solo `for` es suficiente

```
int suma = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++){
   suma += matriz[i][i];
}
```

y para la suma de la diagonal de derecha a izquierda de una matriz cuadrada lo puedes hacer así

```
int suma = 0;

for(int f = 0, c = matriz.length - 1; f < matriz.length && c >= 0 ; f++, c--){
   suma += matriz[f][c];
}
```